# The integral of $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2x}}$

Tags: integration

I need to solve $\int \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2x}}\text{d}x$. I obtained it by calculating the length of the line $l(t)=(t,\sqrt t,\sqrt t)$ for $t\in[1,2].$

Comment: do you try $\frac{1}{2x}=\tan^2\theta$?

Comment: I would start with $u = \sqrt t$ before I even did the differentiation on the curve.

Comment: Your "line" is not a line, it is an arc of a parabola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arc of parabola given by the curve
$$ \gamma(t)=(t,\sqrt{t},\sqrt{t}),\qquad t\in[1,2] $$
has length given by
$$ L= \int_{1}^{2}\left\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\right\|\,dt = \int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2t}}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{\frac{1+u}{u}}\,du = \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{2}\sqrt{1+v^2}\,dv$$
that is:
$$ L = \left.\frac{1}{2}\left(v\sqrt{1+v^2}+\text{arcsinh}(v)\right)\right|_{\sqrt{2}}^{2} =\frac{1}{2}\left(2\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{6}+\log(2+\sqrt{5})-\log(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})\right).$$

Comment: can u explain better the pass from the variable u and v?

Comment: @Mazzorca: $u=v^2$, so that $du = 2v\,dv$.

Answer (score 0):

$u = \sqrt t\\
l(u) = (u^2, u, u)\\
\|\frac {dl}{du}\| = \sqrt {4u^2 + 2}\\
\int_1^{\sqrt 2} \sqrt {4u^2 + 2} du\\
2 u = \sqrt 2 \tan \theta\\
du = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} \sec^2\theta\;d\theta\\
\int_{\tan^{-1}\sqrt 2}^{\tan^{-1} 2} \sqrt {2\tan^2\theta+2}\frac {\sqrt 2}{2} \sec^2\theta\;d\theta\\
\int_{\tan^{-1}\sqrt 2}^{\tan^{-1} 2} \sec^3\theta\;d\theta\\$
$

$\int \sec^3\theta\;d\theta$ is a bit of a tricky one.  You can look it up if you don't know it already:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

$\frac 12 (\sec\theta\tan\theta + \ln(\sec\theta + \tan\theta)|_{\tan^{-1} \sqrt 2}^ {\tan^{-1} 2}\\
\frac 12 (2\sqrt 5  + \ln(2+\sqrt 5) - \sqrt 6 - \ln(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2)$